# I need advice on a good replacement for a transistor

Tags: transistors

I have a Pioneer LX-424 receiver. It is the same as the SX-424.

I need to replace transistors, and I need advice about which transistor I can buy.

The receiver has some 2SC1061 transistors.

I don't know which I can buy them.

I was looking and found these:

- 2SD2125
- 2SC5521
- 2N6488
- MJE15034

I don't which one to use.

Can I use a transistor which has higher collector-emitter voltage?

The 2SC1061 has 50V collector-emitter voltage, and some of them which are recommended have higher collector-emitter voltage.

Comment: No problem to use higher voltage. Depending on what function does it have, some other parameters are more important like hfe.

Comment: I find enough hints when I Google "2sc1061 replacement", the first link is to the audiokarma.org website, showing many people asking the same and getting many suggestions. I suggest you follow the suggestions from that site as here we'll ask about \$h_{FE}\$, \$I_{C,max}\$ and maybe a schematic.

Comment: Why don’t you just buy a 2Sc1061, there seem to be plenty on eBay for example?

Comment: Yet another advice: If this is a part of pre-amp or AB driver, then it has a complementary part PNP. You do have to change both of them and buy then as pair/same lot and not separate. Before you change, find the cause, maybe you gonna need a lab PSU with current limit to be able to correctly adjust the bias.

Answer (score 2):

As @HandyHowie says, there are some listed on eBay. A number of those may be something else re-marked to be what OP desires.

There are some pulls that would probably be okay. Original manufacturer of the C1061 was Hitachi.

There is also the interesting Taiwan-made part with the same part number from [MOSPEC](http://www.mospec.com.tw/pdf/power/2SC1061.pdf). Similar specs, but somewhat lower ft.

Note that the transistors are sold for linear use, so they are beta-binned. Buying them with a random suffix letter results in an almost 10:1 range in possible hFE. So ideally, you want to **match what was in there**.

2SC1061A - hFE 35~70

**2SC1061B** - hFE 60~120

**2SC1061C** - hFE 100~200

2SC1061D - hFE 160~320

You should check out the online sources and service manual for cautions and procedures for bias adjustment.

Apparently the transistors Pioneer used were B or C suffix.

Answer (score 1):

[Schematic downloaded here](https://elektrotanya.com/pioneer_lx-424_stereo_receiver_sch.pdf/download.html#dl)

[image]

[Image source](https://www.industrial-electronics.com/electrnc-dvcs-9e_7.html)

Example of complementary Darlington AB class amplifier, similar as yours but not exactly the same.

[image]

You do have to change both transistors, not a single one, with the equivalent form the same production lot.

- 2SD2125 : No, it's not a TO-220 case
- 2SC5521 : No, it's not a TO-220 case, it's a HV transistor for CRT deflection, not even similar application
- 2N6488 : Maybe, high Ic but low hfe, only 25.
- MJE15034 : Maybe, low Ic rating (still higher than 2SC1061 ) VS. very high Vceo, hfe=100

From your list, the only suitable transistor is MJE15034 (pair, of course).